# Exception in java, print a list

Tags: java, exception

I have a general question about exception.
What should I write so that the whole list is printed?
At the time my output ends by **"String is null"**

Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(list, "hi", null, "hello");

    try {
        print(list);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static void print(List<String> list) {

    for (String string : list) {

        if (string == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("String is null");
        }

        System.out.println(string);

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (string != null) { System.out. println(string); }`

Comment: You could take out the line that throws the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print the whole list, you should use `System.out.println("String is null");` instead of `throw new NullPointerException("String is null");` because the exception stops the program and it can't print the rest of the elements.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(list, "hi", null, "hello");

    try {
        print(list);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static void print(List<String> list) {

    for (String string : list) {
        if (string == null) {
            System.out.println("String is null");
        } else {
          System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can control your flow by checking nullable variables instead of throwing nullpointer exception...

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(list, "hi", null, "hello");
        print(list);
    }

    private static void print(List<String> list) {
        if(list == null ){
            return;
        }
        for (String string : list) {
            if (string == null) {
                System.out.println("String is null");
            } else {
                System.out.println(string);
            }
        }
    }
}
```